# Understanding how to read bevel cuts in woodworking plan?

Tags: woodworking

I'm new to woodworking and I have started a project that requires some bevel cuts. I'm having difficulty understanding and visualizing what it means to make cuts like "10 degrees off square, short point to long point" or something like, "short point to short point measurement, both ends cut at 10 degrees off square" or "10 degree angle, longest point measurement."

What does it mean to cut X degrees off square? Or, cutting something to short point to long point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps

[image]

The easiest way to find/cut the angle is with a speed square.
Here is how to use the speed square to layout an angle:
[How to Set an Angle with a Speed Square](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dyflwC4lfo)

[image]

Comment: oh wow! I had no idea you could use a speed square like that. Thanks for the picture too! That really helps me visualize what the instructions are talking about.

Comment: So if something says, "short point to short point measurement, both ends cut at 10 degrees off square" is the double short point an error?

Comment: aaaaah...I now understand my confusion. I should take the measurement from the location of both short points. It all makes sense now!! :D

Comment: This is a tool that most carpenters have but don't know how to use.  This is a small one in the pic.  They make REALLY big ones.  Use it of stair stringers, roofs, general framing, anything woodworking/building.  Once you know what all the numbers/notches mean, the tools is a real time/lifesaver.  Look at door trim, top piece has 2 "long" and "short" ends and the legs have 1 long and shot end.